# SQL Server stored procedure: setting default value for input parameter though query execution

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, default-value

Suppose I have a following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
   @my_var varbinary
AS
   SELECT @my_var as my_var
```

However I want to modify it so that `@my_var` has a default value. I do not know what that value is literally, but I know where to get it in the database.

Something like:

```
declare @var int
SELECT @var = my_variable from my_table where something = 'what I need'
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE test
    @my_var varbinary = @var
AS
    SELECT @my_var as my_var
```

However, this fails. It seems that @var is falling out of scope.

Is it possible to do something of that kind?

Thank you!

Comment: Will this value ever change, or will it be the same throughout the life of the stored procedure?

Comment: It may, HOWEVER, I only want to execute the query once, grab that value and put it as a default into the SP. In other words, the query may not necessarily return the same value from now till the end of times, but I only care about the value that I am grabbing by means of this query at this current moment, when I am creating the SP. For that reason setting the default to NULL and doing the if check inside the SP and calling a query from there is not an option, unfortunately.

Comment: You do your select _inside_ the proc, right after `AS` and set the value of `@my_var`

Answer (score 2):

To use a value at run time:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
  @my_var varbinary = NULL
AS
BEGIN
IF   @my_var IS NULL
    SELECT @my_var = my_variable from my_table where something = 'what I need'

  SELECT @my_var as my_var
END
```

To use a value at creation time, build a `CREATE PROC` string and execute it

```
declare @var int
declare @SQL VARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @var = id from sysobjects where id =3



SET @SQL = 'CREATE PROCEDURE test @my_var varbinary = ' + CAST(@var AS VARCHAR(20)) + '
AS
    SELECT @my_var as my_var'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

As I mentioned.. if you are only creating this once, why bother making it complicated? If you are creating it many times then you should just do it at runtime. There might be some call to do this if you are deploying to many databases but in that case you might want to consider wrapping this up in a database project

Comment: Will the 1st select query be executed only once, when the stored procedure is created, or will it execute every time that it is called? Thanks!

Comment: every time. Are you worried the value is going to change or are you worried about performance?

Comment: I am not worried about the performance. I am worried that the value may be different. Is there a way to run is just once and hard code that value into the SP?

Comment: Yep you need to use dynamic SQL. You build a big string, concatenate your value into the string and run it with `EXEC`. But if you only create this SP once... whats the point? Conversely, if you create it many times then you may as well select it inside the SP at runtime. Something doesn't make sense here.